# Argument of type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElementEvent<HTMLButton

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is what I am currently working on within my code when I get this error in the console.

```
    type HTMLElementEvent<T extends HTMLElement> = Event & {
    target: T;
}

toggleHandler = (e: HTMLElementEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    console.log(e.target.name)
    this.setState((prevState) =>({isOpen: !prevState.isOpen}))
}

 <button type="button" className={styles.button} onClick={(e) => this.toggleHandler(e)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit with the following code:

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'

toggleHandler = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  // ...your code
}
```

Comment: I want to have access to other methods like name, appendChild and nextElementSibling

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean and want to achieve. Anyway if the answer resolves the question's problem, please consider to mark It as "accepted" and then I suggest you to ask another question, if needed.